# Getting Error when passing function to Child Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I get this error when I am trying to pass my function to Child component: `TypeError: props.replaceVariables is not a function` Am I missing something? As I know I am passing my function correctly. So I can't solve if the problem is inside Player.js or MultipleChoiceType.js.
**My Parent Component:**

```
class Player extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.replaceVariables = this.replaceVariables.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        scope: {},
        variables: this.props.question.data.variables,
        ...
    }

    _renderAnswerInputs(part, partIndex) {
        switch (part.questionType) {
          case Constants.PartMultipleChoiseQuestionType:
            return part.solutions.map((solution, solutionIndex) => {
              return <MultipleChoiceType
                replaceVariables={this.replaceVariables}
                choices={solution[0].choices}
                playerAnswer={this.state.myAnswerPartData?.answers[0]}
                selectedChoiceChanged={(choiceIndex) => this.onChangedMyMultipleChoise(solution[0].choices[choiceIndex], solutionIndex)}
                edit={false} />
            })
        }
    }

    replaceVariables(q) {
        for (var key in this.state.scope) {
          q = this.replaceAll(q, '<span class="mord">' + key + '</span>', '<span class="mord mathdefault">' + this.state.scope[key] + '</span>');
          q = this.replaceAll(q, '<span class="mord mtight">' + key + '</span>', '<span class="mord mathdefault">' + this.state.scope[key] + '</span>');
        };
        return q;
    }
}
...
```

**My Child Component:**

```
function MultipleChoiceType(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.choices?.map((choice, cIndex) => (
                    <div style={{ display: 'flex', padding: 5 }} key={cIndex}>
                        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.replaceVariables(choice.value) }} />
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    )
}
...
```

Comment: `_renderAnswerInputs` may also need to be bound to `this` in the constructor. Can't say for sure, but to verify you can console log `this.replaceVariables` inside the `_renderAnswerInputs` function. If it's undefined thats your problem.

Comment: @BrianThompson I just bounded it like `this._renderAnswerInputs = this._renderAnswerInputs.bind(this)`, but still getting same error

Comment: Ok, did you console log the function inside that method? That would narrow down your debugging search to know if its defined there or not (or not defined as a function somehow)

Comment: @BrianThompson yeah, this is what log displayed: `function () { [native code] }`. I think the problem is somehow related to MultipleChoiceType being function, not a class...

Comment: Its doubtful that its has to do with function vs class. I can't find anything obviously wrong here. Is there any other relevant code? Could you make a runnable example?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried replicate the same behavour and it is running perfectly fine.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fx2gso?file=src%2FApp.js

It must have been something else which is causing this issue.

Answer (score -1):

**Use => arrow functions then you don't need to bind function in constructor**
Try to bind value with function

Edit => try to use arrow functions instead of old syntax

```
<MultipleChoiceType
            replaceVariables={value=>this.replaceVariables(value)}
            choices={solution[0].choices}
            playerAnswer={this.state.myAnswerPartData?.answers[0]}
            selectedChoiceChanged={(choiceIndex) => 
            this.onChangedMyMultipleChoise(solution[0].choices[choiceIndex], 
           solutionIndex)}
            edit={false} />
```